# iOS/OSX CloudKit Operation Speeds

Tags: ios, macos, swift, cloudkit

Ive set up a very basic implementation of CloudKit in my Mac app, yet all queries, saves, and updates, are taking 30-60 seconds to complete.

Is there something I could have misconfigured? Is this normal?

Am I expecting CloudKit to work differently than it was intended to?

Thanks.

```
CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase.saveRecord(record, completionHandler: { (record, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            println("yay")
        } else {
            println(error)
        }
    })
```

Comment: They just update cloudKit and there is the WWDC going on and people testing it and all, it has been much slower than the normal I expect to normalise soon

Comment: Are you experienceing this too and to this extent? All the tutorials I can find show responses in just a second or two.

Comment: It normally is, but since friday has been very slow, at least in the development part of the cloudKit

Comment: Well thanks man, that gave me the green light to keep implementing. I appreciate it!

Comment: Currently all operations take between 0.3 and 1.5 seconds. So it's like it was before.

Comment: Just fired up the app on a different computer, CloudKit operations take place in way less than a second. Still runs slow on my iMac. Any ideas?